# What is the notation $D^2$'s meaning in Evans' Partial Differential Equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

In his book, he did explain that $Du=D_xu=(u_{x_1},\cdots,\,u_{x_n})$. But what it means by writing $D^2u$?

Comment: I can suppose it could be the same notation as $\nabla^2=\Delta$ (the laplacian), but in general the exponent of $D$ should be a multi index.

Comment: Can you give some context? What is $u$ in this situation, and how is $D^2u$ used?

Comment: $|D^2\Psi(x)\leq \frac{C}{|x|^n}\;(x\ne0)|$.

Comment: This notation is quite common in this book, and I'd appreciate someone who have already read this book could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's explained in appendix A, on p. 617.